# Технические работы на сайте PHP

Tags: php, сервер, редирект, контент

Допустим, у нас есть сайт. Как сделать так, чтобы при загрузке любой страницы нас перенаправляло на страницу где сказано что идут технические работы (добавление контента, изменение вида)? Как это сделать на PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Перенаправит на closed.php:

```
<?php
header('Location: closed.php');

// какой-то код
?>
```

Comment: А что если у меня например, форум. Несколько сотен пользователей. Что в каждой странице прописывать? Нельзя ли сделать один файл который деле все за меня (параметры или настройки)? Ну или файл .htacess поправить?

Comment: Заместо "какой - то код" лучше написать exit; дабы быть полностью уверенным в том, что при большом спросе этой страницы сценарий сразу же выйдет.

Comment: Ну exit то понятно. А что с комментарием 1?

Comment: @MrGons18, пропишите в файл, где у Вас происходит к подключение к базу, например.

Comment: В принципе любой форум(если это движок форума) должен иметь у себя в функционале возможность временно закрывать для всех, кроме администраторов доступ. Какой движок?

Comment: Спасибо ModaL!

Comment: У меня не на движке. И я для примера привел

Answer (score 1):

Лучше это сделать с помощью `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!closed\.php$).*$ closed.php [L]
```

Все возможные запросы на одну страницу.
По окончании работ удалить эту строчку из `.htaccess`